# PHP Shuffle Function not working on refresh in IE8 and Chrome

Tags: php

I am using the following php shuffle function code to display a list of images:

```
    <?php
$images = array();
$images['image1'] = array("id" => "sales1", "href" => "#salesperson1", "src" => "salesteam/salesteam-jessie.png");
$images['image2'] = array("id" => "sales2", "href" => "#salesperson2", "src" => "salesteam/salesteam-anthony.png");
$images['image3'] = array("id" => "sales3", "href" => "#salesperson3", "src" => "salesteam/salesteam-nicole1.png");
$images['image4'] = array("id" => "sales4", "href" => "#salesperson4", "src" => "salesteam/salesteam-kevin.png");
$images['image5'] = array("id" => "sales5", "href" => "#salesperson5", "src" => "salesteam/salesteam-christi.png");
$images['image6'] = array("id" => "sales6", "href" => "#salesperson6", "src" => "salesteam/salesteam-thomas.png");
$images['image7'] = array("id" => "sales7", "href" => "#salesperson7", "src" => "salesteam/salesteam-melissa.png");
$images['image8'] = array("id" => "sales8", "href" => "#salesperson8", "src" => "salesteam/salesteam-nicole2.png");
shuffle($images);
foreach ($images as $singleimage) {
$singleid = $singleimage['id'];
$singlehref = $singleimage['href'];
$singlesrc = $singleimage['src'];
echo "<li><a id=\"$singleid\" href=\"$singlehref\"><img src=\"$singlesrc\" /></a></li>";
}
?>
```

It does not work when hitting refresh in either IE8 or Chrome.  It does work just fine in Firefox.  Is it a cache issue?

Comment: Do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5) and if it works on chrome/ie then, it is a caching issue.

Comment: Hard refresh (the above refreshes) does not change the order of the images in IE or Chrome.  Works just fine using a hard refresh or regular refresh in FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can force no caching via http headers

```
<?PHP
header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to the header on this page.  Any other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

It's from cache, you should use as src $imagesrc.'?'.rand(0,999)

```
echo "<li><a id=\"$singleid\" href=\"$singlehref\"><img src=\"$singlesrc?".rand(0,999)."\" /></a></li>";
```

Comment: Yea I tried a similar thing using the time function.  It doesnt seem to work.  In Chrome and IE8 the numbers stay the same. Do you have any other ideas?